# Using Alias Name of Model in Tag Helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I wrote the following C# Model.

```
public class Account
{
    [HiddenInput]
    public int Id { get; set; }                 // id
    public string AccountName { get; set; }     // aName
}
```

And in the Razor page, I wrote the form as follows.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Modify", "Account", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken();
    <input asp-for="Id" />
    <input asp-for="AccountName" />
    <input type="submit" value="Modify" />
}
```

The page was rendered as follows.

```
<form action="/Account/Modify" method="post">
    <input id="Id" name="Id" type="hidden">
    <input id="AccountName" name="AccountName" type="text">
    <input type="submit" value="Modify">
    <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="..."></form>
</form>
```

The result I want is: (id and name of input tag should be displayed as Alias Name of Model)

```
<form action="/Account/Modify" method="post">
    <input id="id" name="id" type="hidden">
    <input id="aName" name="aName" type="text">
    <input type="submit" value="Modify">
    <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="..."></form>
</form>
```

Also, when the form is submitted, it must be accurately bound to the Account Model in the Modify Action of the Account Controller.

How can I give the Model an Alias Name?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could create a model AccountDTO:

```
public class AccountDTO

    {
        [HiddenInput]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [BindProperty(Name = "Acount")]

        public string aname { get; set; }     
    }
```

refer this model in your view so that you could modify your codes as follow:

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken();
    <input asp-for="Id" />
    <input asp-for="aname" />
    <input type="submit" value="Modify" />
```

and in controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> SomeActionName(Account account)

        {
           ......
        }
```

it could bind well.you could use Automapper for complex model as well.